# Replace tokens from list of lists with int value from Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, integer, token

I have a list of lists with only tokens in every list.

```
grade_lists = [['Very good', 'good', 'okay'], ['sufficient', 'bad', 'very bad']]
```

and this dictionary with `key = string`, `value = int`

```
month_ids = {     'Very good': 1,
                  'good': 2,
                  'okay': 3,
                  'sufficient': 4,
                  'bad': 5,
                  'very bad': 6
                  }
```

Can I replace the tokens from my list of lists with the integers from the Dictionary?

```
grade_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
grade_lists = [['Very good', 'good', 'okay'], ['sufficient', 'bad', 'very bad']]
month_ids = {'Very good': 1, 'good': 2, 'okay': 3, 'sufficient': 4, 'bad': 5, 'very bad': 6}
grade_lists2 = [[month_ids[grade] for grade in sublist] for sublist in grade_lists]
print(grade_lists2)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to loop through each list

```
temp_list, new_list = [], []

for glist in grade_lists:
    temp_list = []
    for token in glist:
        temp_list.append(month_ids[token])
    new_list.append(temp_list)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_list
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: It's better to use list comprehensions, as using `append` changes the list size for every added element, which is not efficient. For small lists like this its not substantial, but its anyways better practice to use list comprehensions.